# Two options for the same language in Xcode Localization, which to select

Tags: xcode, localization

When adding Other localization language in Xcode, two options are given for many languages. The reason is unclear. E.g., for Latvian (and other languages) have to select between:

Latvian (lv)    OR    Latvian (Latvia) (lv-LV)

What is the difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lv` is general Latvian. `lv-LV` is Latvia in Latvia.

Pick `lv` if you only support one variant of Latvian.

Since I am more familiar with English I use that as a more thorough example.

There is `en` - general English. Then there is US English - `en-US`, British English - `en-GB`, Australian English - `en-AU`, and several others.

Normally you would want to support `en` as the general English localization. Then if you wanted to also support British English (assuming you used US English for your `en` localization), you could add `en-GB`. Then users can see "color" vs "colour" or "localization" vs "localisation", etc.

Comment: Thanks! So, selecting lv is probably a safe bet. As in many other especially smaller languages, there is only one language style. So, still a bit unsure what the rationale is for offering two options in Xcode.